# Independent format for a string representation of date/time value, for MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a question about MS SQL Server string-to-datetime implicit conversion.

Specifically, can I be sure that a string in the 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' (e.g '2011-04-28 13:01:45') format, inserted into the datetime column, will always be automatically converted to a datetime type, no matter what regional or language settings are used on the server?

If no, does there exist such an independent string format for date time?

Does it depend on MSSQL server version and how?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

If you're using a datetime column (as opposed to the newer types introduced in 2008), the safe format includes the letter T between the date and time components, e.g. `'2011-04-28T13:01:45'`.

For an ambiguous date (where the day <= 12), SQL Server can confuse day and month:

```
set language british
select MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,'2011-04-05 13:01:45'))

----
5

set language british
select MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,'2011-04-05T13:01:45'))

----
4
```

More generally, however, you should find a way to avoid treating datetime values as strings in the first place, e.g. if you're passing this value from some other (non-SQL) code, then use whatever facilities are available in your data access library (e.g. ADO.Net) to pass the value across as a datetime value - let the library deal with any necessary translations.

Comment: You can use `SET DATEFORMAT` to overcome that ambiquity.

Comment: @Remy - true, but when the question says "no matter what regional or language settings...", I assume that calling `SET DATEFORMAT` first is also ruled out (or, for that matter, calling `CONVERT` and using an appropriate non-ambiguous code).

Comment: The "safe format" you refer to is known as "ISO 8601". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx for supported string formats, some of which are not affected by the ambiquity.

Comment: You can also use "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss" which will always be interpreted correctly.